# What's the catkin equivalent of ROS_NOBUILD?

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the catkin equivalent of ROS_NOBUILD? I can't find anything...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186776/what%27s-the-catkin-equivalent-of-ros_nobuild?/) by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CATKIN_IGNORE worked for me the last time I needed it. Not sure if that is a hack though.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-07-16**:
That is fully supported.